# Exclude ASP.NET from subfolders

Tags: php, asp.net

I have an application that runs on a shared hosting website - it is running ASP.NET MVC, however one of the folders within the application, /community/, is just a standalone message board application (Invision Power Board), running in php.

I keep getting problems with the web.config from the asp.net application trying to apply itself to the php application. Can I tell it to somehow ignore the folder with the php application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an ignore route set up in global.asax.cs that will match anything in that folder?  If you ignore the route MVC will not attempt to do anything with it.  Your web.config permissions, etc. will still be in force, but you'll be exempt from the MVC handling.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("php-app/{*pathInfo}");
```