# Ignore folder in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an existing ASP .NET MVC application and I would like to ignore a specific folder within it (where I intend to put PHP scripts).

I have tried adding an ignore route as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352160/exclude-asp-net-from-subfolders/1352168#1352168) but it is not working because I am still getting standard ASP .NET configuration errors.

For examples sake, imagine I have this folder structure:

```
root+
    |
    +--bin
    |
    +--test
```

Based on my understanding, in my global.asax.cs file I think I should be putting this in the RegisterRoutes method:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("test/{*.pathInfo}");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alan

**EDIT: Posted web.config**

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings/>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- Removed -->
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
            <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<system.web.extensions/>
<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <remove name="MvcHttpHandler"/>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

**EDIT: Solution**

What I needed to do was wrap my **system.web** tag in **location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"** to stop these settings propagating into the subfolder. I discovered this [here](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IgnoreRoute you have provided looks fine.
I tested it with Phil Haack's Route Debugger found [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)
It's probably a typo, but did you add this to global.**aspx**.cs or global.**asax**.cs

Comment: OK, what seems to be happening is that it is looking for a dll that is referenced in my web.config file (MySql.Web.dll). I'm not sure why it isn't finding it in this subfolder.

Comment: Can you post your web.config?  Which IIS is this on? I find 7 and 7.5 are much more complicated to setup for things like PHP or ISAPI filters.

Comment: I've added the web.config file. Be aware that I've pruned bits from it that were sensitive. It is quite a big web.config too.

Comment: Ok, so are we still on the PHP error or moved on to something else?  Post the error you are getting now.  Also, if you still have PHP error, try creating a php file and doing a simple phpinfo() to make sure that part works.

Comment: We are still on the "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.1.3.0" error. Sorry, forgot to mention that it is IIS 7 but I have little control over that on my hosting provider. I should also say that PHP isn't that relevant at the moment, my initial test is with just an index.html file and this is failing with the above error.

Comment: I have managed to fix it :) I needed to wrap my <system.web> tag in this <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">. I will post more details in my original question. Thanks for all of your help, I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for those on IIS7+ who keep struggling with this issue even with the suggested solution: you also need to wrap *system.webServer* tag:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Thanks to http://runtingsproper.blogspot.ca/2010/04/solved-breaking-parent-webconfig.html