# Is there a way to have IIS default document (default.asp) take precedence over .Net routing?

Tags: c#, asp-classic, routes, iis-7.5, webmatrix

I am trying to migrate a site from classic ASP to .Net (using WebMatrix).  I am planning on mixing the new .cshmtl pages in with the legacy .asp files and slowly migrate the site over time.  To date, I have individual .asp pages for each piece of content (each url).  As I move to .Net, the content will be coming from a database, so there will not be specific pages for each url.  I love the power of routing that is available in .Net and it works well and plays nicely with the classic ASP with one exception so far.

My example is that I have an ASP page located at /crafts/default.asp and currently reference that everywhere as just /crafts/.  The IIS default document setting takes care of serving the default.asp page when i just reference /crafts/.  I want to start to post new items into this area of the site but run as .Net pages.  so I created a /crafts.cshtml page which is designed to handle different urls and go to the database and lookup the item and display the info.  So as an example I have legacy page at /crafts/fall-crafts.asp and this works fine - because there is an .asp page sitting there named that.  But when i reference /crafts/ .Net takes over and serves the /crafts.cshtml page instead of serving the /crafts/default.asp file.  Is there something I can do to keep the power of .Net routing in place, but still have IIS serve the default document in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your RouteConfig

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("crafts/");
        ...
```

See [RouteCollection.Ignore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784609.aspx) for documentation.

Similar question (mentions some other possibly needed workarounds): [Ignore folder in ASP .NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362925/ignore-folder-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to do this more generically though?  This was just one example and I will have the same problem with all of the directories that have a default.asp page in them that i reference just by the folder name.  So as an example, i have /crafts/fall/, /crafts/winter/, /crafts/summer/, /crafts/spring/, etc. (probably another 100 or so), so it would be great if there was a way to handle more globally without having to put in a specific ignore route for each.

Comment: You could iterate through the folders under the web root and check if they contain default.asp file. If they do, add a route.

Comment: IgnoreRoutes is not available in the Web Pages framework, which is what I believe user1801249 is using (as opposed to MVC)

Comment: @MikeBrind, the question mentions '/crafts.cshtml' - so most probably it is MVC with Razor views.

Comment: @Knaģis cshtml files (along with Razor) were originally developed for the Web Pages framework. The MVC team borrowed Razor and the file type as a new View Engine when they saw how good it was. Plus, you can't do MVC in WebMatrix, which is what user1801249 has tagged the question as. I am certain the application in question is not an MVC one.

Comment: It is so nice to argue about what the author might be using while he himself keeps quiet :)

Comment: Sorry guys - was not available yesterday.  Thanks so much for trying to help!  Mike is correct that I am using WebMatrix and it sounds like the IgnoreRoute option might not work then?  So since my application is not an MVC application, is there any option I have?

Answer (score 0):

The default "routing" built into the Web Pages framework relies on matching incoming URLs to physical files on disk, looking first for the existence of cshtml or vbhtml files. All the time you have a crafts.cshtml file at the same level as a folder called crafts, the file will be served first. The solution is to remove or rename you crafts.cshtml file, but currently that will mess up your URLs.

There is a package which offers greater management over routing in Web Pages applications. It's called Routing For WebPages. It allows you to route URLs to any file name you like. You can download that via the Package Manager or Nuget and read this article that I put together that explains how to use it: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/187/More-Flexible-Routing-For-ASP.NET-Web-Pages.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I just saw your reply here after replying to the previous post above.  I will check out your link and see if that will work for me.  I really appreciate your help!